# Cord Sring - Error en navegador Firefox

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

alguna vez les paso que cuando abren su web en google chrome, internet explore les funciona todo los CORD pero cuando lo abro con Mozilla Firefox me sale este error:

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost:8080/api/login (razón: token 'content-type' no presente en la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' del canal CORS prevuelo).

Alguien me puede decir a que se debe, que mas manda el navegador de firefox que mi navegador lo bloquea.

Comment: ¿Puedes arreglar tu texto, sobre todo en el título de la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Amigo tenia ese mismo problema, en todos los navegadores bien por en firefox no!

la solucion esta en agregarle manualmente los headers que esta usando en el servidor, estoy usando Spring boot con jersey y el filtro me queda asi:

```
@Provider
public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {


    private final static String ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD";
    private final static int MAX_AGE = 42 * 60 * 60;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Client, Secret, Content-Type, *");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE);
    } 
}
```